# How to handle format in perl?

Tags: perl

I want to write the number in two decimal using Perl script. Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

print "Preparing input files\n";

$incr=0.10;

&prepare_input();

exit(0);

sub prepare_input() {
    
    $dist=3;
    while ($dist <= 23) { 
    print "Processing distral: $dist\n";
    &write_mdin0();
    &write_mdin1();
    &write_mdin2();
    &write_disang();
      $dist += $incr;
    }
}

sub write_mdin0 {
    open MDINFILE,'>', "min_mdin.$dist";
    print MDINFILE <<EOF;
#5000 step minimization for $dist ang
 &cntrl
  imin = 1,
  maxcyc=10000, ncyc = 5000,
  ntpr = 100, ntwr = 1000,
  ntf = 1, ntc = 1, cut = 10.0,
  ntb = 1, ntp = 0,
  nmropt = 1,
 &end
 &wt
  type='END',
 &end
DISANG=disang.$dist

EOF
    close MDINFILE;
}
sub write_mdin1 {
    open MDINFILE,'>', "equi_mdin.$dist";
    print MDINFILE <<EOF;
#10 ns NVT equilibration for $dist ang
 &cntrl
  imin = 0, ntx = 1, irest = 0,
  iwrap = 1,
  ntpr = 5000, ntwr = 50000, ntwx = 0,
  ntf = 2, ntc = 2, cut = 10.0,
  ntb = 2, nstlim = 5000000, dt = 0.002,
  tempi=0.0, temp0 = 300.0, ntt = 3,
  gamma_ln = 5.0,
  ntp = 1, pres0 = 1.0, taup = 5.0,
  nmropt = 1, ioutfm=1,
 &end
 &wt
  type='END',
 &end
DISANG=disang.$dist

EOF
    close MDINFILE;
}
sub write_mdin2 {
    open MDINFILE,'>', "prod_mdin.$dist";
    print MDINFILE <<EOF;
#20 ns NPT production for $dist ang
 &cntrl
  imin = 0, ntx = 5, irest = 1,
  iwrap = 1,
  ntpr = 10000, ntwr = 10000, ntwx = 10000,
  ntf = 2, ntc = 2, cut = 10.0,
  ntb = 2, nstlim = 10000000, dt = 0.002,
  temp0 = 300.0, ntt = 3,
  gamma_ln = 5.0,
  ntp = 1, pres0 = 1.0, taup = 5.0,
  nmropt = 1, ioutfm = 1,
 &end
 &wt
  type='DUMPFREQ', istep1=10,
 &end
 &wt
  type='END',
 &end
DISANG=disang.$dist
DUMPAVE=distance_$dist.dat
EOF
    close MDINFILE;
}
sub write_disang {
 $min   = sprintf "%4.6f", $dist;

    open DISANG,'>', "disang.$dist";
    print DISANG <<EOF;
#Harmonic restraints for $dist ang
 &rst iat=-1,-1,0
   r1=0.000000, r2=$min, r3=$min, r4=99.000000, rk2=5.00000, rk3=5.00000,
  IGR1(1)=1,IGR1(2)=5,IGR1(3)=17,IGR1(4)=19,IGR1(5)=21,IGR1(6)=34,IGR1(7)=36,IGR1(8)=38,IGR1(9)=53,IGR1(10)=55,IGR1(11)=57,IGR1(12)=69,IGR1(13)=71,IGR1(14)=73,IGR1(15)=90,IGR1(16)=92,IGR1(17)=94,IGR1(18)=112,
   IGR2(1)=116,IGR2(2)=120,IGR2(3)=132,IGR2(4)=134,IGR2(5)=136,IGR2(6)=149,IGR2(7)=151,IGR2(8)=153,IGR2(9)=168,IGR2(10)=170,IGR2(11)=172,IGR2(12)=184,IGR2(13)=186,IGR2(14)=188,IGR2(15)=205,IGR2(16)=207,IGR2(17)=209,IGR2(18)=227, 
  nstep1=0, nstep2=0,
 &end
EOF
    close DISANG;
}
```

These code generates this kind of files:

```
min_mdin.8.99999999999998
min_mdin.9.09999999999998
```

My aim is to generate the following type of files:

```
min_mdin.9.00
min_mdin.9.10
```

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf

Comment: thanks. I have just added the following line $dist   = sprintf "%4.2f", $dist;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
sprintf "%4.2f"
```

as noted in the comment

Comment: In this site, there's no "tagging" as answered. Anyone can post an answer, like you did here. If an answer is upvoted or accepted, the question is considered answered. So you can edit out the rest and just keep the solution in this post, and it will be a perfectly fine answer.